# Facebook test app usage in automated tests

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Are there someone form facebook team?
Our app has deep integration with FB api and it's critical to test if all works correct. My question is if it's legal to use test app with and test users in our automated tests and run them with headless browser like puppeteer? If not, what alternatives available for us?

Comment: i don´t think it would be a problem with test apps and test users, that´s what they are for anyway.

Comment: @luschn thanks for so quick answer. Just need to be 100% sure, because it will be huge problem if our app gets ban from fb